# How to apply two NOT gates sequentially in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have one signal:

`signal 1 : std_logic :=  '0';`

I want this signal to go through two sequential NOT gates:

`signal 2 : std_logic := not(not(1));`

Two NOT gates will be automatically converted to nothing, but I need two NOT gates to add some signal delay.

It will work if I only have one NOT gate, one NOT gate will be automatically added when signal 2 : `std_logic := not(1);`

Really appreciate it if someone can help.

Comment: Look at your toolchain's synthesis constraint guide for constraints (implemented in VHDL using attributes) named "keep" or "dont_touch" or "preserve" or "no_optimise" or similar. You'll need one on each signal - before, between, and after the NOT operators (or gates). You may need one constraint for synthesis and another for the map/P&R passes. And there doesn't seem to be consistency between toolchains. So experiment using a simple testcase until you get the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what you want is some delay, not really NOT gates.

What do you want that delay for? Adding random gates isn't a reliable solution, logic synthesis will optimize equations as needed. Depending on the layout, crossing inverters make take less time than wiring.

If you want some delay between signals, for example for correct sampling data wrt some another signal, you should place timing constraints, and maybe resample these signals with a clock.

A typical use case for cascading NOT gates is ring oscillators, in that case, special properties are signaled to the synthesiser to disable optimisation. These properties are usually named "SYN_PRESERVE" or "KEEP".

Comment: Really appreciate it! It worked out by disabling the optimization. Actually, my project is similar to the RO. So this is why I choose multiple not gates.